# VS Code Release Notes Showcase Animations Terminal Theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Trying to find the below terminal theme (if this exists at all).

It is shown in the latest Visual Studio Code release notes, checked [oh-my-zsh themes Wiki](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes) (externals too) but no luck.

[image]